# No-API : How to prevent click on parent?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, parent-child

I made my own drag'n drop system, which consists in making a `div` element (= draggable element) containing others elements. I don't use jQuery or HTML5.

Here is how it works :

> When the user triggers the MouseDown event, we make the element draggable.
>     Then : if, when he triggers the MouseUp event (i.e. end of the drag), the program detects that he didn't move the element, it means it was a simple click.
>     Otherwise, it means it was an actual drag'n drop.
>     Thus, the program is able to act in a right way (i.e. according to the existence of a drag'n drop or to a simple click's one)
>     A simple click will hide the element's content. Otherwise, the element is just dropped (= becomes not draggable).

**My problem is :** when I do a simple click on an element of my window, it is hidden. It means the draggable element's events are handled.

**I would want to prevent the draggable element to be clicked when the user clicks on one of its elements.**

Do you know how I could do that cleanly ? Don't hesitate to ask me the code if needed.

Comment: Please read the [help] to see that we do indeed need a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

> I would want to prevent the draggable element to be clicked when the user clicks on one of its elements.

First thing to do in your event handler: check that `event.target` is the same as `this`. If not, exit immediately. Otherwise: you are sure it is the `div` being clicked and not one of its children.

Demo:

```js
document.getElementById('dv').addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    if(e.target !== this) {
      console.log('skip');
      return; // skip
    }
    console.log('mousedown');
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dv">
   test test: mouse down here
   <div>don't respond on this nested element
      <div>And not on this one either</div>
   </div>
   mouse down here
</div>
```

#### Alternative: stop propagation

Another way to achieve the same is stopping the propagation of the event to the parent of an element:

```js
document.getElementById('child').addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    console.log('skip');
    e.stopPropagation();
});

document.getElementById('dv').addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    console.log('mousedown');
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dv">
   test test: mouse down here
   <div id="child">don't respond on this nested element
      <div>And not on this one either</div>
   </div>
   mouse down here
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but according to the way I wrote my system of drag'n drop, I would rather tell a child : "deactivate your parent's onclick's function". I don't want to tell the parent : "don't act if your children are clicked".

Comment: I found event.stopPropagation, I wonder if it's an EcmaScript v.5's function or 6 ?

Comment: There are indeed alternative solutions. `stopPropagation` is a DOM method that has existed for quite some time. It is not defined by EcmaScript, but by W3C. I have added it to my answer as alternative.

Answer (score 0):

> If distance of `x` movement and `y` movement is less than `10` and difference between `mouseDown` and `mouseUp` is greater that `300`, user is about to initiate `click` event or continue with `Drag-Drop` event!

Refer pseudo code from [**`iScroll.js`**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cubiq/iscroll/master/build/iscroll.js):

```js
var point = e.touches ? e.touches[0] : e,
  deltaX = point.pageX - this.pointX,
  deltaY = point.pageY - this.pointY,
  timestamp = utils.getTime(),
  newX, newY,
  absDistX, absDistY;

this.pointX = point.pageX;
this.pointY = point.pageY;

this.distX += deltaX;
this.distY += deltaY;
absDistX = Math.abs(this.distX);
absDistY = Math.abs(this.distY);

// We need to move at least 10 pixels for the scrolling to initiate
if (timestamp - this.endTime > 300 && (absDistX < 10 && absDistY < 10)) { // Click event
  return;
}
```